# I2C failure with stm32

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal, stm32f4, eeprom

I have a problem about I2C and I saw some topics about my problem on the internet but there was no solution, I hope you help me by sheding light on this.

Problem :
 After sending adress by I2C, the ADDR flag in SR1 register is not set but at the same time AF Flag(acknowledge failure) is setting up. I do not use std peripherial libraries and I use stm32f429I-Discovery kit and AT24C256.

It stucks `while (!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0002));`  line, I could not find a solution. Please help me.

```
 /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "main.h"




    int main(void)
    {

        int slave_adress = 0x50; // eeprom adress
        int word_adress = 0x01;  // I want to write in this register adress in eeprom.
              int data = 0x30;  // the data I want to write





        RCC->AHB1ENR |= 1<<1; //enable port B


        RCC->APB1ENR |= 1<<21; // enable  i2c_1 





        GPIOB->MODER    = 0x82000; // made PB6-I2C1_CLK ve PB9-I2C_SDA pins as  alternate function

          GPIOB->AFR[0] = 0x4000000; //  made pb6 as af4 (i2c1_scl)
        GPIOB->AFR[1]   = 0x40;      //    made pb9 as af4 (i2c1_sda)



    GPIOB->OTYPER |= 0x240; //made PB6 and PB9 as open drain 


    GPIOB->PUPDR = 0x00;



    I2C1->CR2 = 0x0010; // made 16MHz clock hsi
    I2C1->CCR = 0x0050; ////SM Mod, duty=0 pclk=16mhz
    I2C1->TRISE = 0x0011; //1000 ns / 62.5 ns = 16 + 1

        I2C1->CR1    = 0x0001;      //enable I2C


I2C1->CR1 |= 1<<8; //I2C Start

            while (!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0001));// //wait for start bit,




            I2C1->DR = slave_adress;                // Write to I2C Address register
            while (!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0002));  ///////////////it stucks here///////////////////////////




            I2C1->DR = word_adress; // (EV8_1 – reference manual)

            while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<7))); // Wait TxE bit set






    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem , my fault was about initialising , the working code is below (I used HAL functions only giving clock):

```
#define eeprom_adress 0xA0
uint8_t data = 0x56;


int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();



    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();


 GPIOB->MODER  |= 0x82000;
 GPIOB->OTYPER |= 0x0240;
 GPIOB->OSPEEDR|= 0xC30C0;
 GPIOB->PUPDR  |= 0x41000;
 GPIOB->AFR[0] |= 0x4000000;
 GPIOB->AFR[1] |= 0x0040;




    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();



    I2C1->OAR1 |= 0x4000;

  I2C1->CR2 |= 0x0003;
    I2C1->CCR |= 0x0010;
    I2C1->TRISE |= 0x004;





        I2C1->CR1 |= 0x0001; //i2c yi enable ettim


        I2C1-> CR1|=1<<8; //start bitini ver

        while(!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0001)); // start bitini bekliyoz

        I2C1->DR = eeprom_adress; // slave cihazin adresini yazdik
    //HAL_Delay(4);
        while(!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0002)); // ADRES GITTIMI
        while(!(I2C1->SR2 &  0x0001)); // MSL ICIN BEKLE

    I2C1->DR = 0x01;

        while(!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0080));

        I2C1->DR = 0x56;


        while(!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0080));  // txe nin bosalmasini bekle
        while(!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0004)); // btf yi bekliyoz

        I2C1->CR1 |= 1<<9; // stop bit


    }
```

Comment: Why you don't work fully with the lib HAL_ is more efficient. try keil ide and stmcubemx

Comment: Hi @TZof, I just wanted to learn about writing codes in register-level, thank you for advice.

Comment: could you be more specific about "my fault was about initialising" ? I have the same issue but your code is completly different so I don't get the critical point.

Comment: I am sorry to answer late, I meant there that I wrote code wrong about setting GPIO to I2C